# How to catch exception then continue processing and then catch another exception and continue processing and so on (C++)

Tags: exception, try-catch, processing, continue

I try to catch exception like this:

```
try
{
    //block code here
}
catch(...)
{
    //write to log file here
}
```

Currently, when an exception happens, it can catch and write to log file. Then it continue processing.
But later, when another exception continue happening, it can not catch anymore but crashes.

So, how to catch exception, then continue processing, then be able to catch exceptions again and again?

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control in a program is quite a wrong-headed way to use the feature.  Many things wrong with it, but for one it causes the *exact* problem you are asking about.  It has everything that's wrong with `goto`, raised to the power of 3.14.  Don't do it.

Comment: Sr, I am not clear abt your answer. Do you mean it is impossible to do that (catch exception, then continue processing, then be able to catch exceptions again and again)?